# RTF control for .Net 1.1 Windows

Tags: .net, controls, rtf

Can anyone recommend a cheap and good RTF control for .Net 1.1 Windows development. It needs to be able to do print/preview and some basic text formatting, fonts etc but nothing too advanced.

Cheers

Andreas

Answer (score 2):

We've used the [TE EDIT](http://www.subsystems.com/tewf.htm) Control from Sub Systems fairly extensively.  We evaluated a lot of controls and found this one to be the best by far.  The API is a little archaic but the tech support was very responsive and we were able to get it to do whatever we needed it to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in rolling out your own, the framework provides a RTF control by default. It's arcane, but one can learn enough RTF to create simple formatting, and printing/print previewing can both be implemented using native classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/WordProcessor09122006234320PM/WordProcessor.aspx) by Scott Lysle provides a good discussion on how to achieve what you want as well as some comprehensive source code to get you started.

Comment: Link now redirects to blank page.